# Return value in atoi function

Tags: java

Currently I have an Atoi function in Java which returns an int value on passing a string input. The initial return value is set to 0. However, the value returned will be 0 if invalid characters or all characters are passed in input string and if the actual string passed is just "0". How can I use return values for these two cases? Or is this okay and I should leave it upto the client to handle this ?

Comment: I am not writing my own function. This is the ambiguity which was asked of me to be resolved in an interview. So, I'm curious what would be the best way to answer this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost certainly *shouldn't* use a return value in that situation - you should probably use an exception.

At that point though, I'm not sure why you're writing your own method in the first place - use `Integer.parseInt` instead.

If you need to be able to convey the notion of invalid input *without* an exception, you could potentially write a method which returns `Integer` instead of `int`, and returns `null` if there's invalid input, and an appropriate `Integer` reference otherwise.

(I'd also point out that Java tends to favour *meaningful* names, rather than somewhat arbitrary collections of letters such as `atoi`.)

Comment: Hi Jon, What if the question is like return whatever int value you have been able to parse so far. So the sequence could be "1a" or "abc" in the first case you return 1 and what would you return in the second case ? Basically in this situation I'd have to return an int. In the 2nd case i'm returning value 0 (initial return value). But I'm curious how to differentiate between "abc" and "0" in both cases i m returning 0.

Comment: @phoenix: That would be a reasonably odd situation to start with - when the requirements are already so specialized, you'd need to do whatever they stated for entirely-invalid input. Why is it important to differentiate between "0" and "abc", but not between "1" and "1abc"?

Comment: because I set the initial return value to 0 so when you parse abc there are no valid digits and the function would return the initial int value which is 0. Now in case of the string being "0" the actual value of the conversion is 0. Would that be okay ? The function requirements are return the int value of digits parsed so "1" and "1abc" will not be a problem because in both cases int value of parsed digits is "1" which is correctly returned.

Comment: Given 'atoi', maybe interviewers were looking for a solution like  this other arbitrary collection of letters: strtol?

Comment: I think it should be noted that it's important to do this consistently: either only throw exceptions when parsing, or return `null`.

Comment: @Pindatjuh: Did anyone suggest having a mixture?

Comment: The name "atoi" is especially funny in Java, since it's quite complicated to work on ASCII in java to start with (you'd have to basically use a byte array, otherwise you're always operating on unicode strings). So first of all we totally have to name this function utoi! :D

Answer (score 2):

This exact function is already handled by the [Integer.parseInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) family of methods. Note the way they handle malformed input: they throw an exception.

You should seriously consider using these methods instead of your own.

Answer (score 1):

If your function were returning a float or double, you could return NaN, but that's not the case.

Don't encode this information in the return value. Throw an exception if you encounter an invalid input string.

Comment: No it shouldn't -- Java has primitive floats and doubles, and object Floats and Doubles, and they behave slightly differently.

Comment: Double.NaN is indeed a double, and Float.NaN is a float - so return Double.NaN in fact returns a double.  I stand corrected :-)

Answer (score 0):

- If zero, 0, is an invalid value, for instance in a banking application transfering money, you won't need to differentiate between *invalid zero*  and *input zero*.
- If negative values are invalid input, you can return *invalid negative one*, -1, as a return value in case of input errors.
- If zero, negative and positive values are all valid inputs, you should consider wrapping the object, for instance using *Integer*.
- If you *must* use a zero to indicate invalid result, and all above cases are not possible to use, add another method, for instance `checkAtoI`, that returns a boolean whether the parsed input is correct. In this case, you can check for *zero* and then call the `checkAtoI` method to know whether it was a valid *zero input*, or an invalid input resulting in a zero, 0, returned integer. This implementation is quite easy too:

  ```
  boolean check(String s) {
      return s.equals("0");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

pay attention: throwing exception is slower then returning null.

My suggest is to return null if parsing failed. But this solution must be taken into account in the  context of the whole your application

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted just the integer prefix of a string, i'd probably use regex to grab just numbers

[0-9]*

and then call Integer.parseInt

on that, something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\s*([0-9]*)");
Match m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.matches())
    return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
else
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to throw an exception which the client would need to handle and then act appropriately, doing so you are delegating the error handling to the client so that as the API implementer you do not have to worry about whether this situation is error, exception or normal for the clients. They will decide and handle the exception (suppress the noise, alert client, ask client to re-enter etc).

Another option would be to return -1 if there is any error in parsing the string, in this case also client will take the decision what to do next.

Although the advantage with throwing an exception is you can always pass details about what the error was in Exception message which is not possible if you pass -1.

```
private static int getDecValue(char hex) {
    int dec = 0;
    switch (hex) {
    case '0':
        dec = 0;
        break;
    case '1':
        dec = 1;
        break;
    case '2':
        dec = 2;
        break;
    case '3':
        dec = 3;
        break;
    case '4':
        dec = 4;
        break;
    case '5':
        dec = 5;
        break;
    case '6':
        dec = 6;
        break;
    case '7':
        dec = 7;
        break;
    case '8':
        dec = 8;
        break;
    case '9':
        dec = 9;
        break;
    default:
        // do nothing
    }
    return dec;
}


public static int atoi(String ascii) throws Exception {
    int integer = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < ascii.length(); index++) {
        if (ascii.charAt(index) >= '0' && ascii.charAt(index) <= '9') {
            integer = (integer * 10) + getDecValue(ascii.charAt(index));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Is not an Integer : " + ascii.charAt(index));
        }
    }
    return integer;
}
```